# Firebase RTDB: Offline cache behaviour issue

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

The issue is about of RTDB (when offline) still return data or just make no callback when I making a request to non-synced node. Plese look at details below.

1. I set offline mode on for my DB: `db.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`
2. I set some node (timeline/240306/trips) as `keepSynced(true)` and it's works as expected
3. Also I set node (timeline/240306/stations) as `keepSynced(false)` and here is an issue

When my phone online all works good. When the phone is offline, I expect my queries to `timeline/240306/stations` should be failed, but they not. As I mentioned above, in this case my request retrives some cached data or just make no any callback at all.

```
        val ref = database
            .getReference("timeline/240306/stations")
            .orderByChild("tripName")
            .equalTo(tripNameDouble)

 ref.get()
.addOnSuccessListener{...}
.addOnFailureListener{...}
.addOnCanceledListener{...}
```

Also I get the following log:

> get for query /timeline/240306/stations falling back to disk cache
> after error: Client is offline

Answer (score 4):

*firebaser here*

Calling `keepSynced(false)` on a path means that any cached values for that path are not automatically updated. It does not necessarily mean that the node doesn't exist in the cache.

There actually is no API call to accomplish the latter, but you can delete the app and its data and reinstall it to start with an empty cache.

---

So the handling should depend on whether there's info about the path in the cache:

- If there is info about the path in the cache, I'd expect your success listener to get called (after the call from the SKD to the server times out).
- If there's no info about the path in the cache, I'd expect your failure listener to get called (after the call from the SDK to the server times out).

---

After conferring with the engineering team, this indeed seems like a bug in the implementation of `get()` on Android. I logged [bug #5771](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5771) for it.

Comment: I see. But why `ref.get()` callbacks dont fire when offline?

Comment: "I see" is a bit little to go on here. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ---

First off, does the explanation of what `keepSynced(false)` does make sense? And does it explain why your approach with that `keepSynced(false)` doesn't work? --- If so: 

1) If there is info about the path in the cache, I'd expect your success listener to get called (after the call from the SKD to the server times out).

2) If there's no info about the path in the cache, I'd expect your failure listener to get called (after the call from the SKD to the server times out).

Comment: Frank, thank you for support. First off, I successfully solve the issue with getting Stations data offline from cache after reinstall my app: it seems some data was stored in cache during dev process.  But I still can't get any callback in this case. So, when asking Station data offline now I get no data — it's good, but I get no callback — that's the issue.

Comment: My libs: firebase-bom:29.0.0. Now I can't use the latest BOM, because my project still not migrated to Android API33

Comment: You're saying you now get no data, but also no error?

Comment: I'm checking on this with the engineer, and it seems that is indeed how it's implemented. We're trying to dig up what it was implemented that way, as clearly you and I both had a different expectation. I'll follow up here once I have more info.

Answer (score 0):

So as a result I had to make some Rx wrapper, aimed to have timeout to RTDB `get()` operation:

```
fun dbReadAsSingle(ref: Query): Single<DataSnapshot>{
    val task = ref.get()
    return Single.create { emitter ->
        task.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful && emitter.isDisposed.not()){
                emitter.onSuccess(task.result)
            } else
                task.exception?.also {
                    emitter.onError(it)
                }
        }
    }
}

FirebaseHelper
    .dbReadAsSingle(ref)
    .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe (...)
```